# Adding events like Oncopy,Oncut,Onpate to a dynamically generated text box

Tags: c#, windows, events, forms, textbox

Hai Guys,

> How to add events like oncopy,onpaste to a dynamically generated textbox in a windows form applications...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd first consider sub-classing TextBox.

If there are "many" of these TextBoxes you will create; I'd think about whether they can and will be possibly removed at run-time, as well as added : whether there are some circumstances in which you would ever want to "dis-connect" one or all of the special events from being processed by one or all of these special TextBoxes.

While you could adopt a strategy of overriding the ProcessCmdKeys for the Form (with Form preview key enabled) to handle globally the issue of relevant keystate at the Form level, I wouldn't go there; I would want to isolate it to the special case textbox. The discussion of ProcessCmdKeys here :

[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704953/try-to-implement-global-keyboard-shortcut-in-mdi-parent-child-form-and-other-form/1705567#1705567)

May be useful to you.

I'd want to create special class to handle instantiation and management of these special textboxes, and their "endownment" with these special event-raisers : you might want to keep a List<TextBox> of the ones currently being used to "track" them. Or, if you are sub-classing, List<SpecialTextBox>.

... note we're skipping over the whole issue of the possibility of a paste or copy being triggered by a selection from the TextBox default menu : are you enabling that ? Is that important to you ? Do you need to "suppress that menu" ? If you wish to still have that menu, and still "catch" the events : imho you are going to have to sub-class TextBox and define a WndProc and catch events like WM_Paste there. ...

There's a pretty complete example of code for sub-classing a TextBox and handling ProcessCmdKeys and trapping the kinds of events you are interested in here :

[link text](http://tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=880710)

But please note I haven't used or tested the above code myself, it was just filed away in my "archive" of snippets, but, at the very least, it will give you a basis for study ... if you have to sub-class.